# how can i make my buttons work? java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I know there are many questions out there regarding action listeners etc.
However, none can help me with my specific issue...no matter which way I try to do it I always get an error.
Here is my simple bouncing ball program:

```
public class ControlledBall extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    int diameter;
    long delay;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int vx;
    private int vy;

    public ControlledBall(int xvelocity, int yvelocity) {


        diameter = 30;
        delay = 40;
        x = 1;
        y = 1;
        vx = xvelocity;
        vy = yvelocity;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillOval(x,y,30,30);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.drawOval(x,y,30,30); //draw
    }

    public void run() {
        while(isVisible()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Something Went Wrong!");
            }
            move();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void move() {
        if(x + vx < 0 || x + diameter + vx > getWidth()) {
            vx *= -1;
        }
        if(y + vy < 0 || y + diameter + vy > getHeight()) {
            vy *= -1;
        }
        x += vx;
        y += vy;

    }

    public void stop(){
        x=0;
        y=0;
    }

    public class Action implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            stop();
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ControlledBall ball2 = new ControlledBall(12,2);
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Controlled Ball");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        window.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
        stop.setSize(4,400);
        stop.setVisible(true);
        stop.setText("Stop");
 //       stop.addActionListener(new Action());

        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

           }
        });

        window.add(stop);
        JButton start = new JButton("Start");
        start.setSize(100,100);
        start.setVisible(true);
        start.setText("Start");
        window.add(start);
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });


        c.ipadx = 400;
        c.ipady = 400;
        c.gridx = 10;
        c.gridy = 10;
        window.add(ball2,c);
       c.ipadx = 50;
      c.ipady = 20;
       c.gridx = 10;
       c.gridy = 10;

        window.pack();
        window.setSize(600,600);
        window.setLocation(250,200);
        window.setVisible(true);


        new Thread(ball2).start();
    }
}
```

as you can see by the commented bits I've tried a few different techniques and none have worked. any advice would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

The main error I get is:

```
non static field cannot be referenced from a static context
```

and I assume that's because I'm running it from the main method.

Comment: What error? That's important. Post it on the question formated as code.

Comment: What line does this error occur on?

Comment: from about line 87 where i try to add the start and stop buttons

Comment: Start by making your `run` method use a Swing `Timer`

Comment: how would i implement and use a swing timer to help in this situation?

Comment: @Javanewbie [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) would be good place to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you really want to do is get rid of your `run` method (and your reliance on `Runnable`).  This is really an inappropriate way to perform regular updates in Swing.

Swing is single threaded and NOT thread safe, your current approach risks dirty read/writes across thread boundaries.

Instead, you want to use a Swing `Timer`, see [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

The next thing you want to do is add a `start` method and update the `stop` method to support the use of a Swing `Timer`...

```
public class ControlledBall extends JPanel {

    //...

    private Timer timer;

    public void stop() {
        if (timer == null) {
            return;
        }
        timer.stop();
        timer = null;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (timer != null) {
            return;
        }
        timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                move();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
```

Then, your start and stop buttons just need to be updated to call these methods...

```
    stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ball2.stop();
        }
    });
    //...
    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ball2.start();
        }
    });
```